# Git same code base but with variations? Inheritance?

Tags: git, github

I am building a portable server - many people will be using the same code.

I want there to be two variations of the code; Personal and Customer.

I want the Customer Variation to be the same code throughout all instances, and the Personal Variation to have custom code but does not affect the Customer Variation.

If I update the Customer Variation then the Personal Variation also gets updated with the new code, but not vice versa.

Essentially, this works similar to inheritance in object-oriented programming, but with code. The Customer Variation would be the default code and the Personal Variation would inherit from it.

Is there something like this in Git? Forks do not seem like the answer, and I am vaguely familiar with branches

Comment: This sounds like a git Master-Development git-flow approach in which all development is performed on a Development branch and Master only contains the latest revisions. Master would be your “customer” branch and Development would be your “personal” branch. Anytime you wanted to submit code to the customer you would merge development/personal into master. 

If you had a “hotfix” or changes directly to master you could merge master (or Customer) code back into development or personal. See Git Flow branching model. https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the main (or master) branch for the Customer variant, and have another branch for Personal that you rebase on top of it every time you create a release.